# Embed images in library project using Monotouch 4.2?

Tags: c#, uiviewcontroller, uiimage, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a library project that contains a couple of `UIViewControllers` that are shared across various applications that make use of the libray.
One of the view controllers needs some images. They are located in my `myLibrary/Controllers/TestController/Images`.

Which build action do I have to specify for the images and how can I access them using `UIImage.From*()` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set a build action of "Content" on each of the images.

Then for referencing the images from code use the following (my images are in the images folder in my project):

```
UIImage.FromFile("images/mycoolimage.png");
```

Comment: One clarification: using Content files in library projects depends on MonoTouch 4.0 or later. MonoDevelop packs them into the dll. When building a MonoTouch app that references the library, MD unpacks the content resources into the app bundle and strips them from the copied dll.